# Layering a div content on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div at the centre . Thats works well but it is not visible on the lower div. i.e the lower div hides the content of the center div. My html code :

```css
.outerWrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #00CCFF;
  height: 350px;
  width: 650px;
}

.layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #6F0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  top: 240px;
  left: 40px;
}

.layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #FC0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 650px;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">1
  <div class="layer1">2</div>
  <div class="layer2">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

> 1. You don't have to use `z-index` for all the div's, if you want a specific div to be in front then just give z-index to that.
> 2. Since you already using `div` in your code, the div will sit beneath another be default and in your case `layer-1` you want that to be in the front, so just use the `z-index` only for that and remove for others.
> 3. The higher the z-index value it display up-front.(in my code it is simple z-index:1`.)

```css
.outerWrap {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00CCFF;
  height: 350px;
  width: 650px;
}

.layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #6F0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  top: 240px;
  left: 40px;
}

.layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FC0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 650px;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">1
  <div class="layer1">2</div>
  <div class="layer2">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got your z-index backwards.  put layer1 at 2 and layer2 at 1

```css
.outerWrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #00CCFF;
  height: 350px;
  width: 650px;
}

.layer1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #6F0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  top: 240px;
  left: 40px;
}

.layer2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FC0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 650px;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">1
  <div class="layer1">2</div>
  <div class="layer2">3</div>
</div>
```